# How do I query a firestore document using firebase_admin with get()

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, python-asyncio, firebase-admin

I am trying to retrieve a document from firestore using python but I keep seeing a context error. Upon some research I found that the firebase_admin sdk is using async calls and python is not waiting, but with that knowledge I am still unable to successfully call the .get() method on a collection reference. Here is an example:

```
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
subscription_data = db.collection("subscriptions").document(purchaseToken)
doc = subscription_data.get()
```

This is the error on the server:

```
RuntimeError: cannot exit context: thread state references a different context object
```

I did attempt to use asyncio with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on [getting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) I see this snippet for doing so in async Python code:

```
doc_ref = db.collection("cities").document("SF")

doc = await doc_ref.get()
if doc.exists:
    print(f"Document data: {doc.to_dict()}")
else:
    print("No such document!")
```

So it seems like `await` might be your way out here.

Comment: Yeah I saw and tried that snippet, I will try again and respond.

Comment: No go on the await, I'm using django and the code doesn't seem to fire when using async

Comment: I believe I am going to go the route of scheduling a task to handle updating firestore. I'm going to setup django q and see where that leads me. I think my biggest issue is I'm trying to perform an async task inside of a synchronous view. I attempted to make the view async but that leads to more errors.

Comment: Quick update. I am getting a bad signature error when trying to use async_task from the djangoq library. I generated a new url safe secret_key and applied that with not luck. Weird thing is the code works locally in development, but not on the production server. This problem is insane!